# Facebook's Graph API is showing much less posts for a page's feed

Tags: java, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am making a Java application for browsing newer and older posts from a Facebook public page.

I have the following code for retrieving the complete feed of posts:

```
    String id = "<my app id>";
    String secret = "<my app secret>";
    String accessToken = "<my app access token>";
    String pageId = "<my page id>";

    ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();
    cb.setRestBaseURL("https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/");
    Facebook fb = new FacebookFactory(cb.build()).getInstance();
    fb.setOAuthAppId(id, secret);
    fb.setOAuthAccessToken(new AccessToken(accessToken));

    ResponseList<Post> posts = fb.getFeed(pageId, (new Reading()).limit(100).includeHidden(true));
    Set<String> postIds = new LinkedHashSet<>();

    do {
        for (Post p : posts) {
            postIds.add(p.getId());
        }
        posts = fb.fetchNext(posts.getPaging());
    } 
    while (posts != null && !posts.isEmpty());

    System.out.println("Number of posts: " + postIds.size());
```

A few months ago (november-december), using this code for a specific page always got me a list with 15000+ posts. A few days ago, without making any modification, I only got 3000+ posts. I have seen similar results with other pages. However, using an older file with the 15000+ post ids made some time ago I determined that many of the posts that weren't showing in the smaller feed still exist and can be accessed using the Graph API.

Why aren't many posts (12000+ for that specific case) showing up anymore? Is it a bug in the Graph API? Is there another way to retrieve the complete feed of posts?

Note: I am using Facebook4j 2.4.8.

Comment: It muse have something to do with `feed` API and access token. Could you try `/posts` endpoint and see if you are getting all the posts?

Comment: @DarshanMehta Yes, I also tried with `/posts` but I get less posts, because the feed also includes posts from visitors.
Don't know if access token has something to do with it.

Comment: Could you check whether your access token still has got manage pages permission (in FB's graph API explorer : https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer)

Comment: @DarshanMehta I used the access token that the explorer gave me, with all permisions checked, and still doesn't work :(

Comment: Can you go to graph API explorer and try retrieving posts from there? It looks like the permissions of your token got changed recently and hence, you are not able to see as many posts.

Comment: @DarshanMehta I also tried that. However, I am still getting around 3000 posts.

Comment: That definitely means access to your token got changed. It no longer has access to see all the page feed.

Comment: @DarshanMehta Then, how can I make it have access to the page's feed again?

Comment: Might be worth contacting Facebook and asking them whether there has been any recent change in your access token permissions.

Comment: I have the same issue except I am using http with v2.11. I page through the page's /feed and I get about 2500 but I have an older table of 15000 posts and they are all retrievable through the API by id. So I know they still exist. I also tried manually with the Graph Explorer, manually clicking the next page link. I get the exact same quantity, about 2500. I also tried /posts and I get around 1000 posts.